# conditional website scraping with bash

Tags: bash, curl, scrape

The following script scrapes a website for movie titles

```
#!/bin/bash
parse_url() {
ids=$(curl -s "$1" | grep -o -P '(?<=list.php\?mid=)\d+')
for id in $ids
do 

titles=$(curl -s "http://subtitle.co.il/view.php?id=$id&m=subtitles#${id#1}" | grep -o -P '(?<=style="direction:ltr;" title=")(.*?)(?=">)')
for title in $titles 
if [[ "$title" == *720p* ]]
then
echo "$title"
fi
done
done
echo "done"
}
```

i want to echo $title only if it contains "720p". when i run the script it returns the following error: syntax error near unexpected token `if'  if [[ "$title" == *720p* ]]'
  where did i go wrong? thanks

Comment: `StackOverflow != FreeProgramming`  ... If you have a specific question, please edit, otherwise your question will likely be closed.\

Comment: sorry, never ment that. thought my question was very specific. i am not asking for someone to write the code for me, just guidance on how to approach the task at hand

Comment: Please, indent your code when you ask help. That will help us & you, trust me.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `do` after the `for` before it.